# Running function from external JS-file when loaded in footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say we have the following page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="myFile.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            test();
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And myFile.js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function test() {
        alert('Hello World!');
    }
});
```

Then console.log will output the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined`

I'd rather not include my .JS files in `<head>` (which I think will solve the problem) since it is more clean to load it after HTML, in footer of page.

Any ideas how to wait for `test();` to run, till `myFile.js` is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `test` on the global scope if you want to use it elsewhere. Also, you don't need to wait for the document to be ready if you're code is in the footer.

```
//$(document).ready(function() {
    function test() {
        alert('Hello World!');
    }
    // add it to global scope
    // window.test = test;
//});
```

and

```
<script>
    //$(document).ready(function() {
        test();
    //});
</script>
```